# Java класс для простой работы с датой и временем

Tags: java, дата, время

Сейчас в проекте есть класс `Date`, где хранится `day`, `month` и `year`. Также есть класс `Time` в котором `hour` и `minute`. У обоих классов есть конструктор. Для каждой переменной есть геттер. Чем можно эти классы заменить, чтобы удобство геттеров не нарушилось?

```
public class Date {

private int day, month, year;

public Date(int day, int month, int year){
    this.day = day;
    this.month = month;
    this.year = year;
}

//getters...

}
```

Класс используется, например, в информации о дне рождения:

```
date.getDay() + "." + date.getMonth() + "." + date.getYear()
```

Comment: То есть у вас два класса. Что на что вы хотите заменить и какое удобство сохранить? Приведите пример того как есть и как в идеале должно быть?

Comment: @Kromster, обновил вопрос

Comment: Все равно непонятно. Почему бы например не объединить оба класса и не хранить и дату и время вместе?

Comment: Чем не угодил LocalDateTime из Java8?

Comment: вам нужно получить дату и время?или как?

Comment: @AseTry, нет, нет, только хранить

Comment: @Kromster, в разных местах используется и то, и другое, не вместе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всей душой против такого варианта, но коли уж ТС настаивает:

```
public class MyDate {
   protected int day, month, year;

   public MyDate(int day, int month, int year){
      this.day = day;
      this.month = month;
      this.year = year;
  }

public class MyDateTime extends MyDate {
   protected int hour, min, sec;

   public MyDateTime(int day, int month, int year, int hour, int min, int sec){
      super(day, month, year);
      this.hour=hour;
      this.min=min;
      this.sec=sec;
   }
```

Вообще непонятно чем не угодил `Calendar` или `LocalDateTime`

Comment: Как раз от этого я хотел избавиться. Мне нужно хранить время отдельно (без секунд), дату отдельно (или с, или без годов) или и то и то вместе. `LocalDateTime` и `Calendar` вроде не предоставят